# localhost:8080 not working for node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, localhost

I recently tried to run node server.js, but for some reason the page is no longer loading, and the browser is just waiting indefinitely. This is the case for both safari and chrome. The code worked fine before and the page would load immediately, but for some reason it stopped working now (not sure if computer updated, or need to install a new version)

If anyone could help figure out why the server will not load it would be greatly appreciated.

my server.js file looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var fundsapp = require('./fundsapp.js');
var app = express();

app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/public/js'));
app.use('/libs', express.static(__dirname + '/public/libs'));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/public/css'));
app.use('/views', express.static(__dirname + '/public/views'));

// app.use('/public/partials', express.static(__dirname + '/public/partials'));
// app.use('/public/js/controllers', express.static(__dirname + '/public/js/controllers'));
// app.use('/public/services', express.static(__dirname + '/public/js/services'))

app.get('/:cik/:startdate/:enddate/:startingtotal', function (req,res) {
  // console.log(fundsapp.absolutedollarvalue(req.params.cik, req.params.startdate, req.params.enddate, req.params.startingtotal))
})

app.get('/api/returns', function(req,res) {
  console.log(req.query)
  fundsapp.calculateReturns(req.query.startDate, req.query.endDate, res, req.query.cik, req.query.benchmark)
})

app.get('/api/adv', function(req,res) {
  console.log(req.query)
  fundsapp.absolutedollarvalue(req.query.startDate, req.query.endDate, req.query.cik, req.query.startingAmount, res)
})

//app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  // res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('public/index.html' , { root : __dirname});
});

app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log("Listening on port 8080")
})
```

my index.html file is below:

```
<!-- public/index.html -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <base href="/">

    <title>Home</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-csp.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> <!-- custom styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.4/angular-material.css">

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/Chart.js/Chart.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.4/angular-material.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-messages.min.js"></script>


    <!-- ANGULAR CUSTOM -->
    <script src="js/controllers/MainCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/TestCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/AdvCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/ReturnsCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/appRoutes.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/config.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="alphaApp" ng-controller="TestController">
<div class="container">

    <!-- HEADER -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Home</a>
        </div>

        <!-- LINK TO OUR PAGES. ANGULAR HANDLES THE ROUTING HERE -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/returns">Returns</a></li>
            <li><a href="/adv">Absolute Returns</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- ANGULAR DYNAMIC CONTENT -->
    <div ng-view></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If any additional information would be helpful please let me know. I'm confused why all of a sudden it stopped loading. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling node, npm, express, and bower to no avail.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:
It looks like from the index.html file it is trying to access the libs folder which I no longer see in the folder. Is there an easy way to install a libs folder filled with the angular files?

Comment: What happens when you start the server? Is there a stack trace?

Comment: It just says "Listening on port 8080"

Comment: Ok. So that's good. Now what happens when you access `localhost:8080`?

Comment: It shows the "Home" in the tab, but then the actual window is just loading. I'm thinking it cannot find the libs folder anymore, but I don't remember deleting libs. Do you know how to install all the angular files in a libs folder?

Comment: Why don't you check your browser console to see what error is being thrown there?

Comment: It says "failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 not found" and it shows the libs files in index.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121800/discussion-between-dustintoothless-and-user3628240).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are referencing the `libs` folder here, for files that don't seem to exist:

> ```
> <script src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
> <script src="libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
> <script src="libs/Chart.js/Chart.js"></script>
> ```

Why don't you change these lines to wherever your vendor js files are?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change port no to any other port like 5000 or 5050, Because you may have any other application running that use that port.

```
app.listen(5000, function() {
  console.log("Listening on port 5000")
})
```

Comment: Didn't work on port 5000, I think there is an issue with not having the necessary files, although I do not remember moving or deleting any files

Comment: @user3273700 Unlikely, because @user3628240 says the server starts up fine with the console log "Listening on post 8080". If it was an issue with the port, node would have thrown an `EDDRINUSE` error